# What is the wpa_supplicant configuration file for a hidden network without password?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I need to connect to a hidden network without password with `wpa_supplicant`:

**`iwlist <interface> scan`  output**:

```
 Cell 02 - Address: 11:22:33:44:55:66
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=##################
                    Extra: Last beacon: 248ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: ######
                    IE: Unknown: ##################
                    IE: Unknown: #####
                    IE: Unknown: ##############
                    IE: Unknown: ######
                    IE: Unknown: ###############
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: ###################
```

**What is the `wpa_supplicant` configuration file needed to connect to this network?**

---

Wrong guess:

```
network={
    ssid=""
    bssid=11:22:33:44:55:66
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiki-Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connection) you should add `scan_ssid=1` to your `wpa_supplicant` configuration file:

> **Tip**: To configure a network block to a hidden wireless SSID, which by definition will not turn up in a regular scan, the option `scan_ssid=1` has to be defined in the network block.

to connect to an open network, you need to add the `key_mgmt=NONE` option to your `wpa_supplicant` configuration file :

```
network={
        ssid=""
        bssid=11:22:33:44:55:66
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me (wrong conf file).